# TestFlight bug type 179

Tags: testflight

I have recently uploaded an app to be tested through TestFlight. The app successfully works on two of the three internal testers' devices, but the third cannot move past the first screen. The error he is sending me says ""bug_type":"179","os_version":"iPhone OS 10.2 (14C92)"}". Does anyone have any idea what this means or where I can start to identify the problem he is specifically having?

Comment: Can you please share - what did you find out about this? I am having the same issue in a live app.